# searching for a bijective relationship between a specific set and an interval on the natural numbers

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given a set S, with |S|=n,
there are several sets Pi (which contain sets) that satisfy the following conditions:
1: Every element of S is contained in exactly one element of Pi.
2: Pi does not contain the empty set.
3: the union of all elements of Pi is S.

Example: S={a,b,c,d,e} => {{a,d},{b,c},{e}} ist ein Pi.

Let R be a set that contains all Pi's and only Pi's.

Its obvious that for one choice of S, there is only one unique R.

Example:
[image]

Let m be |R|.

Let I be {x|(x e N) and x <= m}.

It is clear that the value of m depends only on the value of n.

Also, it is obvious that there are several bijective Relations between R and I.

What I need is:

a function b(x) that takes n as argument and returns the corresponding m.

a bijective function p(x) : I -> R.

Also, the evaluation of both functions should be "as simple as possible".
I need this for a computer algorithm that relies on both functions (but especially p(x)) being blazingly efficient.

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far and how have they failed? Also, take a look at a MathJax tutorial such as this one, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Sadly, I have no idea how to do that. Assigning an unique natural number to every Pi seems easy, but I cannot accept any "gaps" between the natural numbers assigned to the Pi's, since that would ruin efficiency.

Comment: Your $b(x)$ is the so called $x$-th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Comment: Wow. Thats already half of the answer.

Comment: You can inductively generate all *partitions* of a finite set, and meanwhile you can simply index them (arrange the partitions in an array, but beware to remove duplicate elements - - $b(n)$ will be the length of the array, and the indices give you the bijection).

Comment: Well, that would work perfectly fine if I wanted to generate them all, but there are too many of them when n gets large enough.

Comment: @Gae.S. : Your finding that b(x) is the x-th Bell number may actually enable me to create a program that evaluates p(x) semi-efficiently.